# Debugging rtf to text function

Tags: sql-server, rtf

I have a function we use to convert RTF formatted text to plain text. It has worked pretty well in the past, and seems to work pretty well so far on the text in question.

However, somewhere in my dataset of 230,000 records, it makes a bad SUBSTRING call and aborts the entire thing (without telling me the offending record).

Is there any way I can get some feedback into what is going on?
I know that SQLServer functions do not allow PRINT statements, or INSERT statements.
And the dataset of 230,000 records is not mine, but a clients. I really don't want to have to try to go record by record and see which one is causing the error.

SQL Function below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RTF2Text]
(
    @rtf nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Pos1 int;
DECLARE @Pos2 int;
DECLARE @hex varchar(316);
DECLARE @Stage table
(
    [Char] char(1),
    [Pos] int
);
INSERT @Stage
    (
       [Char]
     , [Pos]
    )
SELECT SUBSTRING(@rtf, [Number], 1)
     , [Number]
  FROM [master]..[spt_values]
 WHERE ([Type] = 'p')
   AND (SUBSTRING(@rtf, Number, 1) IN ('{', '}'));
SELECT @Pos1 = MIN([Pos])
     , @Pos2 = MAX([Pos])
  FROM @Stage;
DELETE
  FROM @Stage
 WHERE ([Pos] IN (@Pos1, @Pos2));
WHILE (1 = 1)
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @Pos1 = s1.[Pos]
             , @Pos2 = s2.[Pos]
          FROM @Stage s1
            INNER JOIN @Stage s2 ON s2.[Pos] > s1.[Pos]
         WHERE (s1.[Char] = '{')
           AND (s2.[Char] = '}')
        ORDER BY s2.[Pos] - s1.[Pos];
        IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
            BREAK
        DELETE
          FROM @Stage
         WHERE ([Pos] IN (@Pos1, @Pos2));
        UPDATE @Stage
           SET [Pos] = [Pos] - @Pos2 + @Pos1 - 1
         WHERE ([Pos] > @Pos2);
        SET @rtf = STUFF(@rtf, @Pos1, @Pos2 - @Pos1 + 1, '');
    END
SET @rtf = REPLACE(@rtf, '\pard', '^*^');
SET @rtf = REPLACE(@rtf, '\par', '^*^');
SET @rtf = REPLACE(@rtf, '\t', '^~^');
SET @rtf = STUFF(@rtf, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @rtf), '');
IF len(@rtf) > 0
    WHILE (Right(@rtf, 1) IN (' ', CHAR(13), CHAR(10), '}'))
      BEGIN
        SELECT @rtf = SUBSTRING(@rtf, 1, (LEN(@rtf + 'x') - 2));
        IF LEN(@rtf) = 0 BREAK
    END
SET @Pos1 = CHARINDEX('\''', @rtf);
WHILE @Pos1 IS NOT NULL AND @Pos1 > 0
    BEGIN
        IF @Pos1 IS NOT NULL AND @Pos1 > 0
            BEGIN
                SET @hex = '0x' + SUBSTRING(@rtf, @Pos1 + 2, 2);
                SET @rtf = REPLACE(@rtf, SUBSTRING(@rtf, @Pos1, 4), CHAR(CONVERT(int, CONVERT (binary(1), @hex,1))));
                SET @Pos1 = CHARINDEX('\''', @rtf);
            END
    END
SET @rtf = COALESCE(@rtf, '') + ' ';
SET @Pos1 = PATINDEX('%\%[0123456789][\ ]%', @rtf);
WHILE @Pos1 IS NOT NULL AND @Pos1 > 0 AND @rtf != ''
    BEGIN
        SET @Pos2 = CHARINDEX(' ', @rtf, @Pos1 + 1);
        IF @Pos2 < @Pos1
            SET @Pos2 = CHARINDEX('\', @rtf, @Pos1 + 1);
        IF @Pos2 < @Pos1
            BEGIN
                SET @rtf = SUBSTRING(@rtf, 1, @Pos1 - 1);
                SET @Pos1 = 0;
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @rtf = STUFF(@rtf, @Pos1, @Pos2 - @Pos1 + 1, '');
                SET @Pos1 = PATINDEX('%\%[0123456789][\ ]%', @rtf);
            END
    END
IF RIGHT(@rtf, 1) = ' '
    SET @rtf = SUBSTRING(@rtf, 1, LEN(@rtf) -1);
RETURN @rtf;
END
```

Comment: divide your function to some parts. and when you are using insert, update or delete use transaction, try catch. it will be esier

Answer (score 0):

Not to be too rude, but have you actually tested on your function?

Have you run any unit tests to try and break your function, e.g. invalid values, boundary conditions etc.?

Have you checked documentation to see under what conditions [`SUBSTRING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql) can throw an exception?

I have run these cases and am getting exceptions:

```
SELECT dbo.[RTF2Text]( NULL )
SELECT dbo.[RTF2Text]( '' )
SELECT dbo.[RTF2Text]( '1' )
SELECT dbo.[RTF2Text]( 'blah' )
```

If you know under what conditions/input values your function will fail, then it is a simple matter of checking for these in your table.

Comment: The function itself is some code found, probably here, to strip RTF. (Some of our clients use legacy systems with RTF encoding, and we do not support that.) So the function has been tested as many times as it has been used, sadly. Which is seldom .

Comment: It should have been tested as soon as it got to your system, but failing that, now is as good a time as ever. As the answer above demostrates, 15 minutes is all it takes for a few simple cases.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation and have very little knowledge of SQL functions however needed to strip RTF and tried this code. Debugging suggested that this function was failing was here as I was getting Invalid length parameter.

```
IF RIGHT(@rtf, 1) = ' '
    SET @rtf = SUBSTRING(@rtf, 1, LEN(@rtf) -1);
```

As I have minimal knowledge and lack of time I just added a second if to make sure it wasn't doing a subtraction i.e. -1 from 0 which worked for my dataset.

```
    IF RIGHT(@rtf, 1) = ' '
IF LEN(@rtf) > 0
    SET @rtf = SUBSTRING(@rtf, 1, LEN(@rtf) -1);
```